# Acesso externo ao tomcat do eclipse

Tags: tomcat

Estou criando um web service para ser consumido por aplicação mobile, em java, utilizando tomcat como container.
Está funcionando porem, para cada vez que vou testar tenho que fazer deploy pois o tomcat do eclipse não aceita conexão de outro host.
Alguem sabe como configurar o tomcat no eclipse para aceitar esses acessos externos?

Comment: Você está tentando acessar de fora ou dentro da sua rede local? Estou achando estranho pois o tomcat não tem esse tipo de bloqueio por padrão e o eclipse também não restringe isso, acredito que seria mais uma questão de rede.

Comment: está dentro da minha rede local.

Comment: Já verificou o firewall da máquina onde está rodando o eclipse?

Comment: amigo não acedito que seja firewall, pois caso fosse eu não teria acesso quando faço deploy no tomcat direto.

Comment: Qual sistema operacional usas? Podes postar o teu server.xml?